# Get value of exactly where two moving averages cross?

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to get the value of exactly where two moving averages cross? Eg see this chart - the two MAs appear to cross between the `18:05` and `18:06` bars, at a value of what appears to be `1855.64`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's a math question about the intersection point of two line segments.
So you have one line segment `(x1, y1), (x2, y2)` and another line segment `(u1, v1), (u2, v2)`.

The intersection point (x,y) can be solved by

```
x = -1 * ((x1 - x2) * (u1 * v2 - u2 * v1) - (u2 - u1) * (x2 * y1 - x1 * y2)) / ((v1 - v2) * (x1 - x2) - (u2 - u1) * (y2 - y1))

y = -1 * (u1 * v2 * y1 - u1 * v2 * y2 - u2 * v1 * y1 + u2 * v1 * y2 - v1 * x1 * y2 + v1 * x2 * y1 + v2 * x1 * y2 - v2 * x2 * y1) / (-1 * u1 * y1 + u1 * y2 + u2 * y1 - u2 * y2 + v1 * x1 - v1 * x2 - v2 * x1 + v2 * x2)
```

I'm guessing you only need the `y` coordinate.
Complete explanation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375083/given-coordinates-of-beginning-and-end-of-two-intersecting-line-segments-how-do).

Here's a Pine Script code example:

```
//@version=4
study(title="intersection point", overlay=true)

var float   last_intersect_x    = na
var float   last_intersect_y    = na

// Gets intersection point of two line segments [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)] and [(u1, v1), (u2, v2)].
f_get_intersect_coordinates(x1, y1, x2, y2, u1, v1, u2, v2) =>
    x = -1 * ((x1 - x2) * (u1 * v2 - u2 * v1) - (u2 - u1) * (x2 * y1 - x1 * y2)) / ((v1 - v2) * (x1 - x2) - (u2 - u1) * (y2 - y1))
    y = -1 * (u1 * v2 * y1 - u1 * v2 * y2 - u2 * v1 * y1 + u2 * v1 * y2 - v1 * x1 * y2 + v1 * x2 * y1 + v2 * x1 * y2 - v2 * x2 * y1) / (-1 * u1 * y1 + u1 * y2 + u2 * y1 - u2 * y2 + v1 * x1 - v1 * x2 - v2 * x1 + v2 * x2)
    [x,y]

sma10 = sma(close, 10)
sma50 = sma(close, 50)

if cross(sma10, sma50)
    x1 = bar_index[1]
    y1 = sma10[1]
    x2 = bar_index
    y2 = sma10
    u1 = bar_index[1]
    v1 = sma50[1]
    u2 = bar_index
    v2 = sma50
    
    [x,y] = f_get_intersect_coordinates(x1, y1, x2, y2, u1, v1, u2, v2)
    
    last_intersect_x := x
    last_intersect_y := y

    line.new(bar_index-1, last_intersect_y, bar_index, last_intersect_y, extend=extend.right, color=color.yellow, style=line.style_dashed)
    label.new(bar_index, last_intersect_y, "x = " + tostring(last_intersect_x, "#.##") + "\ny = " + tostring(last_intersect_y, "#.##"), yloc=yloc.abovebar)


plot(sma10, "sma10", color.green)
plot(sma50, "sma50", color.blue)

// Debug
// plotchar(last_intersect_x, "lix", "")
// plotchar(last_intersect_y, "liy", "")
```

Which yields this on ticker `AAPL`

[image: AAPL crossover coordinates]

Comment: Thanks Bjorn. By x1, x2, etc, do you mean x[1], x[2], etc in Pine Script? While I get that this problem is in the most important ways a math problem, I need to apply it to a Pine Script as an answer to the question. Thanks, please confirm! :-)

Comment: No, the x1, x2, etc... are the coordinates of the line segments. I updated my answer with a working Pine Script code example.